# Column repeat direction in microsoft report viewer

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer, microsoft-reporting

I am using windows form to generate Identity Card using c# and Microsoft report viewer. Everything is working fine except I could not find column repeat direction in Microsoft report viewer.

**Current Scenario**

My report paper size is A4. Each page can display maximum 10 individual cards. There are 2 columns in page. Each column display 5 cards. It is generating card as shown in image. The column repeat direction is vertically. It first list 1st column (1-5) and then list 2nd column (6-10).

[image]

**My Requirement**

I want the report column repeat direction to be horizontally like in  the image below. First display 1 then 2 and 3 and 4 and so on.

[image]

**Why I want to display horizontally rather than vertically?**

It will save the paper. For example, if the user generate 4 Identity cards only then as per current scenario, it will generate 4 cards in column 1 and the whole page space is wasted because I can not re-use the left space.

By repeating the column direction to horizontally, the 4 cards will be displayed as in column 1, card 1 and 3 and in column 2, card 2 and 4 will  be displayed. I can then cut the paper and reuse it later.

I have searched alot but could not find any solution. Any suggestion, comments or links will be helpful. I can not use any other reports. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume your cards are rows in a report? If so, could you post the code that generates each identity card?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a matrix

Define your row grouping as

```
=Ceiling(Fields!CardNo.Value/2)
```

Define your column grouping as

```
=Fields!CardNo.Value Mod 2
```

Your report design will look something like this. *Outer group is just shown for illustration purposes but you can delete it.*

[image]

Now when you run the report. You will get the result you are looking for

[image]

Without any grouping header and footer. Your report output will be

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be seen as mapping problem where you need to reshuffle your items as follow:

```
n -> f(n)
----------
1 -> 1
2 -> 6
3 -> 2
4 -> 7
5 -> 3
6 -> 8
7 -> 4
8 -> 9
9 -> 5
10 -> 10

n is the original position
f(n) is the mapped position
```

It can be seen that it follows a pattern like this:

1. `f(n) = floor(n / 2) + 1`  if n is odd
2. `f(n) = (10 + n) / 2` if n is even

Thus, you may want to reshuffle the order you put your items in that following manner. That is given `index` of the item from 0-9 (start from 0 is following C# typical number indexer), you could do something like this:

```
index++;
int newIndex = index % 2 == 0 ? (10 + index) / 2 : index / 2 + 1;
newIndex--;
```

And you should be able to place your `Cards` correctly.

Note: without actually code given, this is to show how you can solve the problem conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer. This will work with or without groups on your tables.

Place two tables side by side on your report. Set the first table to a query that partitions starting at the first record and skipping by 1. Next, set the second table to a query that partitions starting at the second record skipping by 1.